# React Native Firebase Analytics: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, cocoapods, react-native-firebase

I'm trying to build an iOS development build of my Expo project for an iOS simulator. I'm developing the app using the managed workflow with a custom development client.

My project depends on a suite of [React Native Firebase libraries](https://rnfirebase.io/), including Firestore and Auth. Recently, I also added [Analytics](https://rnfirebase.io/analytics/usage) by executing `expo install @react-native-firebase/analytics`. When I tried to build the project with `expo run:ios`, I got the following error.

```
❌  Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64
┌─ Symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRAnalytics
└─ Referenced from: objc-class-ref in RNFBAnalyticsModule.o


❌  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64



❌  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

    Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the my_project_name editor. (in target 'my_project_name' from project 'my_project_name')
```

[This is the link to the minimum, reproducible example](https://github.com/hayata-suenaga/analytics) on github. Please run `expo run:ios` after `expo install`.

- Tried to clear caches by following instructions on [expo doc](https://docs.expo.dev/troubleshooting/clear-cache-macos-linux/#expo-cli-and-npm).
- Deleted the `ios` directory.
- Manually installed pods by running `pod install` inside the `ios` directory.

None of the above solutions worked. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that my setting for a [config plugin](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/config-plugins/) (that writes configurations for native projects) was wrong.

`firebase-ios-sdk` requires [the usage of frameworks](https://rnfirebase.io/#altering-cocoapods-to-use-frameworks). To specify this on a managed Expo project, you need to install a config plugin called `expo-build-properties` and edit the plugin property of `app.json` like following:

```
[
  "expo-build-properties",
  {
    "ios": {
      "useFrameworks": "static"
    }
  }
]
```

In my original code, instead of `static`, I specified `dynamic`, which was causing the error.